# Mongodb, parse a variable as query condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is the code:

```
const indexString = [ "project.", index, ".fileInfo.$.fileStyle" ];
var indexS = indexString.join('');
var condition = {
   $and: [
      { _id: req.user._id },
      { "project.fileInfo.fileName": req.body.fileName }
   ]
};

var testQuery = {
   $set: { indexS: req.body.position } 
};

await User.updateOne(condition, testQuery, function (err, res) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    User.close;
})
```

As you can see, I want to use `indexS` in the query.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `[]` to use the value of a variable as a `key`.

In your case,

```js
var indexS = 'project.0.fileInfo.$.fileStyle';

var testQuery = {$set:{indexS: 'position'}}
console.log(testQuery) ---> { "$set" : { "indexS" : "position" } } // Here the key is set as indexS

// Using []
var testQuery = {$set:{[indexS]: 'position'}}. // Using [] on indexS variable 
console.log(testQuery) ---> { "$set" : { "project.0.fileInfo.$.fileStyle" : "position" } }
```